# Error 403 trying to generate access token for service account on GCP using terraform

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am trying to generate an access token for one of my service accounts in GCP within terraform. The plan is to use this token to authenticate a docker provider so that it can push images to the artifact registry defined within the same module. However, when I try to run `terraform apply` I get the following error: `Error: googleapi: Error 403: Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist)`.

It seems that I require the `iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken` permission (or the `iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator` role) but I'm not sure on what? My terraform is authenticated using credentials for a service account with full `Owner` permissions and I've tried adding the above role to the service account I'm trying to impersonate, but not had any luck.

My full terraform module is the following:

```
resource "google_artifact_registry_repository" "registry" {
  location      = var.gcp_region
  repository_id = "frontend-repository"
  description   = "front end artifact registry"
  format        = "DOCKER"
}

resource "google_service_account" "service_account" {
  account_id   = "artifact-registry-sa"
  display_name = "Artifact Registry Service Account"
  project      = var.gcp_project
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "service_account_registry_permission" {
  project = var.gcp_project
  role    = "roles/artifactregistry.repoAdmin"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.service_account.email}"
}

data "google_service_account_access_token" "access_token" {
  target_service_account = google_service_account.service_account.email
  scopes                 = ["cloud-platform"]
  lifetime               = "300s"
}
```

In addition I have tried adding the following permissions to my code, but have not had any luck yet.

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "service_account_access_token_permission" {
  project = var.gcp_project
  role    = "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator"
  member  = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.service_account.email}"
}

data "google_client_openid_userinfo" "me" { }

resource "google_service_account_iam_binding" "token-creator-iam" {
    service_account_id = google_service_account.service_account.name
    role               = "roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator"
    members = [
        "serviceAccount:${data.google_client_openid_userinfo.me.email}",
    ]
}
```

**Edit**
Adding in the code in my main block which calls this module

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = file(pathexpand("~/GCP_credentials/my-app-terraform.json"))
  project     = var.gcp_project
  region      = var.gcp_region
  zone        = var.gcp_zone
}

module "artifact_registry" {
  source      = "./artifact_registry"
  gcp_project = var.gcp_project
  gcp_region  = var.gcp_region
}
```

Here `my-app-terraform.json` is an access key generated from my `terraform` service account, which I have given full Owner permissions.

I have already confirmed the following:

1. I am able to create resources using this setup (e.g., if I comment out the access key, the rest of the resources are created correctly)
2. I am authenticated as my terraform SA. I output `google_client_openid_userinfo.me.email` and it matched the email address of the terraform SA.

Comment: The Google identity that you are using to authorize Terraform (Application Default Credentials - ADC) does not have permission to create tokens from the service account `google_service_account.service_account.email`. The required role is `roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator`. Your post does not show how you are authorizing Terraform, but I recommend specifying the credentials in the provider block to use so that you do not need to guess.

Comment: I've added in the block where I'm authorising terraform above. I only have one provider so I'm assuming that's the identity I'm using. That identity has full Owner permissions.

Comment: You need the permission `iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken`. The IAM role `roles/owner` does not have that permission. Add the IAM role `roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator` either at the project level or at the target service account `google_service_account.service_account.email` Note: many assume that the Owner role has all permissions - it does not. You can use the command `gcloud iam roles describe roles/owner` to see which permissions an IAM role has.

Comment: Suggestion: Never give a service account or regular users the Owner role. That should be attached to a Google user identity and then locked away. Only log in with Owner permissions when necessary. Allocate the absolute minimum permissions required to service accounts and regular users including yourself.